# Client is not defined discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to send a message to a specific channel using

```
client.channels.cache.get(`channelID`).send(`Text`)
```

but it always says

> "ReferenceError: client is not defined".

In my `index.js` file, however, I have

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
```

and do not understand why I still get this error.

All involved code:

logban.js:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'logban',
    description: "Logs a ban",
    execute(message, args, Discord) {
        let player = args[0]
        let length = args[1]
        let reason = args.slice(2).join(' ');
        if (reason.length > 1024) reason = reason.slice(0, 1015) + '...';
    if(!args[0]){
        message.channel.send("/logban <player> <length> <reason>")
        return;
    };
    if(!args[2]) reason = 'Not Specified'
    if(!args[1]) length = 'Not Specified'
 
    const banReport = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#00e698')
                .setTitle('BAN REPORT')
                .addFields(
                    {name: 'Player', value: player},
                    {name: 'Reason', value: reason},
                    {name: 'Time & Date', value: message.createdAt},
                    {name: 'Length', value: length},
                    {name: 'Moderator', value: `<@${message.author.id}>`},
                )
                client.channels.cache.get(`805219773830266902`).send(banReport);
 
    }
}
```

index.js:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
 
const client = new Discord.Client();
 
const prefix = '/';
 
const fs = require('fs');
 
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
 
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
 
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
 
 
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is online!');
});
 
client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
 
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
 
    if(command === 'logban'){
        client.commands.get('logban').execute(message, args, Discord);
    }
});
```

Comment: Show all of the related code to give us a better idea of the issue.

Comment: Show more code, it's clear that the aforementioned line of code is not executed before accessing the channels property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call

```
client.channels.cache.get(`805219773830266902`).send(banReport)
```

You are calling it in your command file, which doesn't have access to `client`.
You could simply change your `execute` function to pass in the `client`:

```
client.commands.get('logban').execute(message, args, Discord, client);
```

And then the method signature for `execute` becomes

```
execute(message, args, Discord, client) {
```

That way, you can access the client in the execute function of your command.

You could also remove passing `Discord` in the method call for `execute` and import the parts you need to in your command, which in your case would be `MessageEmbed`

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')
const banReport = new MessageEmbed()...
```

Then your `execute` call becomes

```
client.commands.get('logban').execute(message, args, client);
```

And the method signature becomes:

```
execute(message, args, client) {
```